# IN operator in Cassandra doesn't work for table having a column with type-collection(Map or List)

Tags: cassandra, nosql

I'm working on Cassandra, trying to get to know how it works. Encountered something strange while using IN operator. Example:

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE test_time (
  name text,
  age int,
  time timeuuid,
  "timestamp" timestamp,
  PRIMARY KEY ((name, age), time)
)
```

I have inserted few dummy data. Used IN operator as follows:

```
SELECT * from test_time
where name="9" and age=81
and time IN (c7c88000-190e-11e4-8000-000000000000, c7c88000-190e-11e4-7000-000000000000);
```

It worked properly.

Then, added a column of type `Map`. Table will look like:

```
CREATE TABLE test_time (
  name text,
  age int,
  time timeuuid,
  name_age map<text, int>,
  "timestamp" timestamp,
  PRIMARY KEY ((name, age), time)
)
```

On executing same query, I got following error:

> Bad Request: Cannot restrict PRIMARY KEY part time by IN relation as a collection is selected by the query

From the above examples, we can say, IN operator doesn't work if there are any column of type collection(Map or List) in the table.

I don't understand why it behaves like this. Please let me know If I'm missing anything here. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yup...that is a limitation. You can do the following:

1. `select * from ...where name='9' and age=81 and time > x and time < y`
2. `select [columns except collection] from ...where name='9' and age=81 and time in (...)`

You can then filter client side, or do another query.

Comment: Thanks.. I got it. Do have any idea why it is designed liked this. Why collection is creating such a problem?

Comment: Might be because cassandra can't make assumptions about data layout on disk. Maybe they'll fix it in the future.

Comment: Thanks.. Hope they fix it. Looks odd.

Answer (score 0):

You can either include your column as a part of partitioning expression in the primary key

```
CREATE TABLE test_time (
  name text,
  age int,
  time timeuuid,
  "timestamp" timestamp,
  PRIMARY KEY ((name, time), age)
);
```

or create a separate Materialized View to satisfy your query requirements:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW test_time_mv AS
SELECT * FROM test_time
WHERE name IS NOT NULL AND time IS NOT NULL AND age IS NOT NULL
PRIMARY KEY ((name, time), age);
```

Now use the Materialized View in your query instead of the base table:

```
    SELECT * from test_time_mv 
    where name='9' 
      and age=81 
      and time IN (c7c88000-190e-11e4-8000-000000000000, 
        c7c88000-190e-11e4-7000-000000000000);
```