# Cannot fetch data from cassandra using cqlengine python model :

Tags: python, cassandra, cqlengine

I am trying to use the cassandrapython cqlengine for accessing the cassandra db, I was able to filter when the columns are not of list type.

I get the following error message :

```
d =cClass().filter(lastname='text',age=2,input__contains='a') 

Traceback (most recent call last):   
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/cqlengine-0.21.0-py3.4.egg/cqlengine/operators.py", line 43, 
    in get_operator KeyError: 'CONTAINS'  During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:  
Traceback (most recent call last):   
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>   
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/cqlengine-0.21.0-py3.4.egg/cqlengine/models.py", line 562, in filter   
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/cqlengine-0.21.0-py3.4.egg/cqlengine/query.py", line 507, in filter   
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/cqlengine-0.21.0-py3.4.egg/cqlengine/operators.py", line 45, 
    in get_operator **cqlengine.operators.QueryOperatorException: contains doesn't map to a QueryOperator**
```

Comment: Look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25076283 . I guess it is the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using a very old (and deprecated) version of cqlengine. If you can, upgrade to the version integrated with the [DataStax driver](https://github.com/datastax/python-driver#datastax-python-driver-for-apache-cassandra), where the API has supported `contains` [since version 3.1.0](https://github.com/datastax/python-driver/commit/21b8fac563817918bf973437fc4f953ab8e7ec36).